# Two different polite forms of the conditional conjugation

Tags: verbs, classical-japanese, conditionals

I've noticed some dictionaries give two different results for the polite form of the conditional form, I'll use the verb 戦う for example.

I am familiar with 戦いませば but not with 戦いますれば.

Some dictionaries give just one, others give both.

Is there a difference in these two in anyway?

Are both frequently used?

Comment: Are both frequently used? >> No, not in modern Japanese. They sound archaic. We'd rather use 戦いましたら

Comment: Koden, are you an advanced learner who is dealing with classic/archaic Japanese? If not, I'm sure you have mistyped or misread something.

Comment: these are the polite present form conditional conjugations that some dictionaries give
いませば　is very common

Comment: Koden, what dictionaries are you using?

Comment: いませば is the most common form of the polite present conditional conjugation in all of the dictionaries I check
but I actually found the answer after looking for several hours so this question should be deleted or closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither is common. In fact, 戦いませば and 戦いますれば are almost *never* used in modern Japanese. You have to use 戦いましたら.

- I sometimes hear stereotyped samurai in samurai dramas say 戦いますれば. It's indeed "if (someone) fights" said in a polite way. It's "stereotyped samurai-ish speech", but I don't know whether old people actually talked like this. People never use it today except as a joke.
- いませば is occasionally found in archaic Japanese documents, Bible translations, hymn books, and so on. But actually it's [在【いま】す](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%99) followed by ば.
- 戦いませば, ございませば, ありませば, etc. should be extremely rare, and I would say it's nearly wrong (but apparently a few people seem to use ございませば...). If used, it would leave a very literary, archaic, and/or odd impression.

Comment: when I said "common" I didnt mean common in speech or usage, I meant dictionaries will show that conjugation frequently

Comment: Okay, ます seems to be the 仮定形 of ます (according to [this](http://homepage3.nifty.com/jgrammar/ja/data/conjugat.htm)). I personally don't remember seeing this except in clearly 文語調/武士言葉 documents, but one answer here in [this question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1175969906) says ～ますれば was not too rare until 30 years ago.