Is the polite provisional form used?
In my textbook which has been highly accurate and recommended (Basic Japanese by Erik Sato), there is a section about being polite. It talks about conjugations of ます like まして, ましたら, and ませ (e.g くださいませ) on the end of verbs (usually honorific) though I can't find the negative and past for only mase. I have also found evidence of these and in a lot of stack exchange post and online in honorific / けいご language. However there is also one polite verb ending for provisional - ませば used in けいご like the others. I can't find any evidence or conjugation of this so I am wondering whether ませば is used as verb ending japanese (keigo)

Are you asking, "does such a form exist", or "is such a form used"?  These are two different things.  We have historical evidence of ～ませんかった and ～ませなんだ in wide use in the past, for instance, as the polite negative past-tense, but these are obsolete and not part of the modern language.

I mean used in modern day japanese language - used often. Like how mashite or mashitara are often used and spoken in Japanese keigo / exalted / honorific language.

It seems like ますれば might be preferable to ませば, but it any case, neither form is common in modern Japanese:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33233/two-different-polite-forms-of-the-conditional-conjugation

In the post, firstly they say not to use it but to use mashitara. Isn't this conditional got a different use / differently used to provisional conditional. Secondly is there a polite provisional form because there are polite forms which people use often in modern japanese like polite  (ましたら) and polite gerund (まして), and polite imperative (mase) (found in keigo sentences)

デジタル大辞泉 suggests 「ますなら」 in this note: 仮定形「ますれ」はほとんど用いられず、代わって「ますなら」が多く使われる https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/ます/#jn-208067

In modern Japanese, ます conjugations are normally only used on verbs at the end of a sentence (like how です is normally only used at the end; in the middle we use な - the attributive form of だ - or else である). These conjugations exist, and follow regular patterns, but aren't ordinarily used - politeness, humility and formality are marked in other ways, such as prefixing nouns with 御 (お・ご・おん). Tae Kim has some good introductory material on this.
One notable exception is the expression はじめまして, from はじめる "to begin (tr.)". This is commonly used by itself, so it doesn't cause any grammatical complications.
If you aren't finding a conjugations "for only mase", that's because this ます is considered only an auxiliary with no real meaning on its own - you can't use it by itself as a verb any more than you could use たい by itself as an i-adjective. (There's 在す, but that's archaic; and 増す, but that's an unrelated homophone.)
